# "Install Guest Additions" - nothing happens

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, guest-additions

I want to (re)install the Guest Additions in order to run Age of Empires 2 on virtutalbox as described [here](https://www.jethrocarr.com/2013/04/20/age-of-empires-2-hd-on-virtualbox/). When I press "Devices -> Install Guest Additions" nothing happens. How can I start this?

```
Host: Kubuntu 14.4
Guest: Windows 7 Ultimate
VirtualBox: 5.0.18 r111378
```

Answer (score 7):

**This is a general Answer/Solution** for the primary question asked (for Ubuntu, Kubuntu, etc. with virtual Windows (7) running in VirtualBox):

-Remember to download Guest Additions.iso-file from package manager separately, since it does not automatically come with Virtualbox download!

1. Windows (7) **has by default** installation **Autostart disabled/turned off** and ***that is why Guest Additions will not start installation*** from *VirtualBox Devices-tab*.
2. **Instead** you need to install Guest Additions **from/inside/within your virtual Windows operating system**, and that's **Easy Enough:**
3. *Download* Virtualbox Guest Additions ISO with a package manager like Muon or Synaptic.
4. *Click* "Insert Guest Additions CD image" in VirtualBox Devices-tab in a running Virtual Windows that you have earlier created, shown in the screenshot.
5. *Open* File Manager in virtual Windows
6. *Double-click* Computer Icon
7. *Double-click* CD-drive (Drive D) and you'll see a list of VBoxWindowsAdditions.exe -files
8. *Double-click* the VBoxWindowsAdditions.exe file suitable for your operating system (x86 for 32 Bit operating system) and **installation will start.**

This is shown in a screenshot below: **File Manager of Virtual Windows 7 running in VirtualBox** [in Suomi-language (Finnish) - Native language of Mr., DSc Linus Torvalds - Founder of Linux Operating System] **in Kubuntu 18.04**.]

[image: mounted_virtualbox_guest_cd_drive]

Below citation from Oracle VirtualBox User Manual, Chapter 4.2, Installing and Maintaining Guest Additions, page 66 ([link](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#additions-windows)):

> Unless you have the Autostart feature disabled in your Windows guest, Windows will now
> autostart the VirtualBox Guest Additions installation program from the Additions ISO. **If the
> Autostart feature has been turned off, choose VBoxWindowsAdditions.exe from the CD/DVD
> drive inside the guest to start the installer.**
> The installer will add several device drivers to the Windows driver database and then invoke
> the hardware detection wizard.
> Depending on your configuration, it might display warnings that the drivers are not digitally
> signed. You must confirm these in order to continue the installation and properly install the
> Additions.
> After installation, reboot your guest operating system to activate the Additions.

Answer to two guestions asked (This was a too long answer to be added as comment). Mostly i am just repeating myself:

If you have a Linux computer and a Windows op. sys. opened in Virtualbox, you open Windows File Manager or Explorer (the yellow folder icon). Under Computer icon (Tietokone* in suomi-language at the screenshot)  you should have a similar screen as in the screenshot, if you have downloaded Guest Additions from from a Package manager like Muon or Synaptic and from The Devices-tab (second from left at top panel of virtual windows) selected "Install Guest Additions ISO".

(* If you are interested in linguistics; word 'tieto' means knowledge in suomi-language and 'kone' means machine, so computer = tietokone = knowledgemachine)

If you do not see Virtualbox Guest Additions as Drive D (CD-Drive), it means you have not downloaded the guest additions - do it again.

If you have succeeded in downloading Guest Additions, you should have a similar view as in the screenshot when you click CD-Drive under Computer in Explorer in Virtual Windows.

You just double-click the x86- (highlighted with blue) or amd64- icon depending on if you are installing a 32 Bit virtual Windows or a 64 Bit virtual Windows. After that Virtualbox Guest Additions download program should start and guide you through the rest of the installation.

Comment: so what I do I do after downloading the file "Guest Additions.iso-file"?

Comment: should i download "Guest Additions.iso-file" on the guest os?

Answer (score -1):

It's quite easy actually:

```
Open the explorer in the guest and start manually from cd.
```

[image]