# Cannot install guestadditions for virtualbox 5.2.6

Tags: virtualbox, linux-mint, guest-additions

I have installed virtualbox 5.2.6 on a Linux Mint 18.3 host. As a guest I have installed Windows 10 v1709. I have trouble to add the guest additions. I installed version 5.2.6 manually because the version provided with the package manager does not run the Windows 10 installer. This version does. However, I cannot install the guestadditions.iso.

When I boot then one of the boot messages is:

```
Failed to start: vboxadd.service
```

[This article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169024/how-can-i-tell-if-the-virtualbox-guest-additions-were-installed-on-an-ubuntu-vm) described how I could test for the presence of the guestadditions. I did the following:

```
$ lsmod | grep vboxguest
(ml-gpu) arnold@orlandus ~
$ sudo modprobe vboxadd
modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxadd not found in directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-42-generic
(ml-gpu) arnold@orlandus ~
$ sudo modprobe vboxvfs
modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxvfs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-42-generic
```

I gathered that this output meant there are no guestadditions present. Next I tried to install the guest additions into the virtual machine. I started my windows 10 guest and went to devices | optical disk | choose disk image where I added VBoxGuestAdditions_5.2.6.iso. Next I went to devices | Insert guest addtions CD image and nothing happens. I removed the CD and tried again: same result.

Anybody any idea how can I add guest addtions?

Comment: If you browse to the cd and execute the exe or msi manually? That should at least work.

Comment: It was as simple as that. Thanks very much for the suggestion!

Comment: Great. :) I've posted you an answer, so you can mark this question as Solved. This will help others know that you no longer need help.

Comment: Same answer as LPChip. See detailed solution in: https://superuser.com/questions/1145603/install-guest-additions-nothing-happens/1413143#1413143

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you why autorun didn't work, but you should at least be able to simply browse to the virtual drive in the explorer and start the installer/setup by double clicking it.